# What is a "mike"?

Tags: terminology, divisibility

The MultiBit website [mentions](https://multibit.org/blog/2014/03/17/multibit-hd-sneak-preview.html) Bitcoin amounts being showns as "mikes":

> Everybody has a different way of wanting to display their balances and this is especially true when dealing with different countries and languages. Users of MultiBit HD can now fine tune their own display to exactly match what they want. Support is in place for millis, mikes and satoshis along with different presentation styles including the icon, "BTC" and "XBT".

What is a "mike" and why is it named such?

Comment: related: [Naming convention: MilliBit or Millibitcoins (mBTC), microbitcoin or Mikrobitcoins (μBTC)?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/16887/5406)

Answer (score 5):

One ***mike*** is one microbitcoin, i.e. 0.000001 BTC or 100 satoshis.

It's called like that only because it sounds similar.

Comment: Yet the current consensus seems to be to call this a bit. Most wallets have switched or will switch soon (or at least have it as an option). So it's probably best to forget about "mike" again.

Comment: http://www.btcsatoshi.com/ gives a nice overview of the different "tiers".