# What is a mBTC?

Tags: terminology, divisibility

I have been trying to find out just what is an `mBTC` is. Everywhere I look I cannot find out what the value is compared to a Bitcoin.

I was hoping you could advise me of what the value is.

Comment: I'd have thought that we have that question already, but we actually don't have it yet! Nice find. ;) These are somewhat related: [What is a 'Satoshi'?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/114/5406), [Naming convention: MilliBit or Millibitcoins (mBTC), microbitcoin or Mikrobitcoins (μBTC)?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/16887/5406)

Answer (score 16):

`m` is the symbol for the [metric prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) `milli` which indicates a unit to be one thousandth of its base unit.

A millibitcoin therefore is 0.001 BTC or 1/1000 BTC.

Answer (score 5):

mBTC stands for milliBTC. Just like millimeter or millivolt, milli indicates 1/1000th in the metric system.

Answer (score -1):

mBTC is also know as millibitcoin and it also one thousandth of a BTC (1 mBTC = 0.001 BTC) and there is another unit μBTC also known as microbitcoin and it is also one millionth of a BTC.

Comment: I've edited this answer because it contained grammar errors that made it somewhat confusing. However, in my opinion this answer doesn't add new content, rather it repeats previous answers.

Answer (score -3):

A millibitcoin  is 0.001 BTC. But an easier way to remember is one satoshi is one hundred millionth of a bit coin.

```
Ten Satoshi                              = one Ith     I 
one hundred Satoshi                      = one Hish    H     
one thousand Satoshi                     = one Shi     S
ten thousand Satoshi                     = one Oth     O
one hundred thousand Satoshi             = one Tish    T
one million Satoshi                      = one Ash     A 
ten million Satoshi                      = one Sha     S
```

Comment: Are these standard units?  What is the source for this?