# Is definition of Bitcoin changed over time?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Asking on behalf of *skang404* based on this comment: [Is bitcoin a common noun or a proper noun?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/115591/is-bitcoin-a-common-noun-or-a-proper-noun/115592?noredirect=1#comment131587_115592)

I understand there some answers for [What is Bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/what-is-bitcoin) but things have changed since 2012-14.

Even I am curious to learn what bitcoin is.

Comment: The fundamental essence of what Bitcoin is hasn't changed since 2012.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/what-is-bitcoin)

Answer (score -1):

Yes only if some major upgrades happens on the particular blockchain than the definition could be changed i.e ethereum moved from proof of work to proof of exchange in the recent times.